# Download Data in Excel using Asp.net core WEB Api

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need To get the records in Excel format. but I'm getting an error at last.can someone give me a solution where I'm making mistake?
API which im coding. When I click on Execute it has to be written back excel sheet with the required information from a database.
while return result(at the last) im getting error.

```
            var query = await _eventScheduleContext
                                .ViewPersonEvent
                                .Where(x => x.ExamModeId == examModeID)
                                .Where(x => x.EventStatusId == eventstatusscheduleID)
                                .Where(x => x.DateTimeUtc.Date >= startDate && x.DateTimeUtc.Date <= endDate)
                                .Select(x => new OnlineSchedule()
                                {
                                    PersonEventId = x.PersonEventId,
                                    PersonTenantRoleId = x.PersonTenantRoleId,
                                    FirstName = x.FirstName,
                                    LastName = x.LastName,
                                    EmailId = x.EmailId,
                                    ExamName = x.ExamName,
                                    DateTimeUtc = x.DateTimeUtc,
                                    TimeZoneCode = x.TimeZoneCode,
                                    EventStatus = x.EventStatus,
                                    CreatedOn = x.CreatedOn,
                                    UserName = x.EmailId,
                                    Password = x.PersonTenantRoleId

                                })
                                         .ToListAsync();



            var result = query
                      ?.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeUtc)
                      ?.ToList();

            result?.ForEach(r =>
            {
                r.UserName = r.EmailId;
                r.Password = r.PersonTenantRoleId;

                if (r.CreatedOn > new DateTime(2022, 08, 01, 2, 40, 0))
                {
                    r.UserName = r.PersonTenantRoleId.ToString();
                }

            });

            using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("OnlineScheduleList");
                var currentRow = 1;


                #region Header
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "PersonEventID";
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "PersonTenantRoleId";
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "FirstName";
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "LastName";
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "EmailId";
                #endregion

                #region Body
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    currentRow++;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = item.PersonEventId;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = item.PersonTenantRoleId;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 3).Value = item.FirstName;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 4).Value = item.LastName;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 5).Value = item.EmailId;
                }
                #endregion

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                    var content = stream.ToArray();

                    return result(
                        content,
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                        "Students.xlsx"
                        );
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

> I need To get the records in Excel format. but I'm getting an error at
> last.can someone give me a solution where I'm making mistake?

It seems that your query has not return the data as expected so you are getting the error. First make sure your query is valid and fetching the correct data. you can try with demo data. However, I have successfully implemented that and getting expected `excel`. You could follow below steps:

**Model I have Used:**

```cs
public class Member
    {
      
        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Gender { get; set; }

        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

       
    }
```

**Controller:**

```cs
public IActionResult Excel()
        {
            //Getting Member List
            var membersList = _context.Members.ToList();

            using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("MemberList");
                var currentRow = 1;

                //Excel Header
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "MemberId";
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = "Name";
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 3).Value = "Gender";
                worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 4).Value = "DOB";

                //Excel Body
                foreach (var member in membersList)
                {
                    currentRow++;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = member.MemberId;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = member.Name;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 3).Value = member.Gender;
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 4).Value = member.DOB;
                }

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                    var content = stream.ToArray();

                    return File(
                        content,
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                        "Members.xlsx");
                }
            }
        }
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Nuget Package:**

I have used [`ClosedXML`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/) nuget package `v-0.96.0` to generate the `excel`.

Comment: Error im Getting is "Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: last we mentioning return File (content,"")...Am getting error in File

Comment: Could you please your full controller code other then your method? Which `version of asp.net` project you are using? I am using in `asp.net 6` as you can see the output without any issue.

Comment: If you have written this method out side from the `controller class` then it wouldn't work. Must be within `Asp.net controller class`

Comment: If the answer as helpful you could accept the solution by right clicking beside your question. If other community member encounter the same problem may get benefited.